# MVC storing date without time

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datepicker

I am trying to save the date the user enters into a database. The problem is that despite only the date showing in the text box the time is also being saved. This is what it looks like in my model.

```
{11/02/2015 00:00:00}
```

However this is what I have in my JQuery set up and how I would like it to look when saved to the database, without the time also attached.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

I assume the problem lies in my model somewhere so this is how I have it set up at the moment.

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateOfBooking { get; set; }
```

and this is my view,

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBooking, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBooking, new { @id = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBooking)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the data type for that column in your database?

Comment: It will be datetime like shown in my model? I should point out it outputs the correct result on the view, the only problem is that it is saved in my DB in a way that I don't want it. For example - '2015-02-18 00:00:00.000'

Answer (score 3):

There's no way, using DateTimes, to only store/pass the date to the model. In SQL you can use a [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) data type that will only store the Date part of the DateTime object from .Net. However, when you move data into/out of your model you'll always have a time component. The easiest way is to just ignore the time component and specify the display format like you're doing.

You could also use something like [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) that has structs for Date only types.

Comment: Ah OK, good to know. I can easily just ignore it, so that's fine. Just wanted to know if there was a 'better' approach.