# How to insert only date in database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC code for inserting date is:

My view:

```
Prescription Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="prescriptiondate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><br />
```

My model:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtprescriptiondate", medsamp.prescriptiondate);
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Addvalues(string patientcodenew, string yes, string no, string medication, string qty, string strength, string prn, string form, string route, string dosage, string quantity, string potency, string rxsource, string listqualifier, string icd10, string directionfrequency, string prescriptiondate, string startdate, string enddate, string renewaldate, string discontinuedate, string changedate, string pharmacy, string substitution, string dayssupply, string status)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    mt.prescriptiondate = Convert.ToDateTime(prescriptiondate);
    return View("Index",dv);
}
```

Comment: The table you are inserting into, make sure the PrescriptionDate field is a Date field instead of DateTime.  Can you show your table structure?

Comment: [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[medication]([prescriptiondate] [varchar](50) NULL)

Comment: And if `prescriptiondate` is a date, then make the parameter `DateTime prescriptiondate`, not `string prescriptiondate`

Comment: @ashwanth your field is already a `varchar` field. So what you are doing is,  Convert `String` -> `DateTime` object -> `SQL text field`, which is unnecessary. Quick way to do is `mt.prescriptiondate = Convert.ToDateTime(prescriptiondate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` or, depend on your front end , you can remove the Convert line of code

Comment: so i need to convert my prescriptiondate (datatype) to date in sql @jacky

Comment: Seems your problem is similar with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588394/mvc-storing-date-without-time. Converting into `date` datatype simply enough, but remember that when pulling it from DB it requires `DateTime` structure with default time (the time component can be ignored).

Comment: If you're storing dates in the database as `varchar`, you're Doing It Wrong(TM). If you're accepting string data from the user - like you want them to be able to type "the twenty-second day of August, two thousand and seventeen", validate this and convert it to `DateTime` first before passing the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you have

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[medication]([prescriptiondate] varchar NULL)

prescriptiondate if of string type so try this ;

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdtprescriptiondate", medsamp.prescriptiondate.ToShortDateString()); 
    DateTime dt = DateTime.now;
    String date = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

//ToShortDateString will give you only datePart.